# why isn't this code working?-Filing Through Scanner and PrintWriter

Tags: java

I don't know whats wrong with the code and I don't even know the basics of filing though. Anyone please help.
Its taking input of marks and reg no and even marks but doesn't display Marks 
What should i do?

```
       class Info
            {
              public void writeFile() throws IOException{

     try{
         FileWriter f = new FileWriter("D:\\Student.txt");

      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(f) ;
      System.out.println("Enter Student's Name");
      String name=in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter Student's Reg.No");
      String reg_no=in.nextLine();
      Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Student's marks");
      int marks=inp.nextInt();
      fw.write(name);
      fw.write(reg_no);
      fw.write(marks) ;
      fw.close();
     }
      catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }

  }

    public void readFile() throws IOException
    {
       try{ 
           FileReader reader =new FileReader("D:\\Student.txt");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(reader);
        while(in.hasNext())
         System.out.println(in.next());
         reader.close();

 }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `fw.write(marks);` after this line `int marks=inp.nextInt();` your passing `marks` which is `int` to `write(int c)` which is in `PrintWriter` class

```
/**
     * Writes a single character.
     * @param c int specifying a character to be written.
     */
    public void write(int c) {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                ensureOpen();
                out.write(c);
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

which is responsible to write your `int` as single `character` not as int value, if we go deeper it is calling `write(int c)` in `StreamEncoder` class if you see source code of this method

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {
   char cbuf[] = new char[1];
   cbuf[0] = (char) c;
   write(cbuf, 0, 1);
}
```

it is taking your `int` value and converting it into `char` and storing into `char` which means it is storing equivalent `char` value for your `int`
If you want your expected output change your code

`int marks=inp.nextInt();` --> `String marks=inp.nextLine();`

Comment: Thankyou so much :) 
Nd what i'd do to save and display it in next line ?

Comment: what do you mean "to save and display in next line?"

Comment: I meant that I want it to save it like this 
Ali
288
09 
but it displays as Ali28809
How would i use tab or new line escape sequence here?

Answer (score 0):

try to append some extra space to your String while writing the code like

```
System.out.println("Enter Student's Name");
String name=in.nextLine()+" ";
```

finally your string `Ali28809` will store like this `Ali 288 09` 
and while reading the data you will get 
`Ali
288
09`

If you want your output like same as you stored in your file like `Ali 288 09`
change your code in `readFile()`  use `nexLine()` instead of `next()`

```
FileReader reader =new FileReader("D:\\Student.txt");
Scanner in=new Scanner(reader);
while(in.hasNext());
System.out.print(in.nextLine()); //here is the change
 reader.close();
```

and your output is `Ali 288 09` hope this will help you

Comment: Yes it did :) Thankyou so much

Comment: Sorry i wasn't known that i even have to accept it :)